# How to Use letsencrypt/certbot to get certification for .app domain

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, .app

I have a `.app` domain and would like to use letsencrypt/certbot to generate ssl certificates. Based on the instructions in https://certbot.eff.org/, I will need to have an HTTP website running on this domain to get the ssl certification using certbot.

However, the `.app` domain does not allow any http traffic, thus I cannot setup an http website on this domain.

Here is the error code that I see:

```
Fetching https://<my_server_ip>/.well-known/acme-challenge/MA8bj-<code>: Invalid host in redirect target "<my_server_ip>". Only domain names are supported, not IP addresses
```

I am wondering how I can get the ssl certificate using certbot for `.app` domain. I cannot find much information about this issue. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: What does this means: app domain does not allow any http traffic, thus I cannot setup an http website on this domain?

Comment: These domains are https forced by Google for enhanced security. Here is more information: https://get.app/

Comment: Did you try to install and use cerbot or just read instructions?

Comment: What errors you encounter while trying install or use certbot? I believe you may just install use it.

Comment: Yes, i did try to install the certificate. I updated the question with the error

Comment: It says "Only domain names are supported, not IP addresses" What you do not understand here? HTTPS with certifcates use DNS names, not ip. Add nginx site config to your question so i can inspect it. I guess your server_name is wrong.

Comment: Thank you @gapsf . Yes, that is right. The issue was that I had configured redirect instead of DNS record in my domain configuration. After creating the DNS record and removing the redirect, it started to work. Thanks again for helping to debug this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue was that I had configured redirect instead of DNS record in my domain configuration. After creating the DNS record and removing the redirect, it started to work well.